# Divisibility of partial sum and difference of integers

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The problem is this:

Given a set of integers `A` and another integer `k > 1`, is it possible to partition `A` into two subsets whose sum is `x` and `y` respectively, of which `(x - y) mod k = 0`

It is obvious that there is a time complexity `O(2^N)` algorithm by listing all possible partitions, but is there a more efficient one? Or is this equivalent to the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to the subset sum indeed, and can be solved efficiently (pseudo polynomial time) using the DP solution, since your numbers are integers.

A simple solution to it is using the Dynamic Programming solution of subset sum:

```
D(0,i) = true     i >= 0
D(x,0) = false    x != 0
D(x,i) = D(x-arr[i],i-1) OR D(x,i-1)
```

By building the DP table (in bottom-up solution), all you have to do when you are done is to check if there is any `x` such that:

```
D(x,n) = true, abs(x-(SUM-x)) % k = 0
Where:
n - number of elements
SUM = arr[1] + arr[2] + ... + arr[n]
k - the given integer for mod
(x-y) % k = (x-(SUM-x)) % k
```

---

However, for small values of `k`, you can optimize it to be `O(n*k)` (rather than `O(n*SUM)`. This is still pseudo-polynomial time, but could be huge improvement if `k << SUM`.

First note that  `x-y = x-(SUM-x) = 2x-SUM`, and you are looking for a subset that sums to `x` such that `2x - SUM % k = 0`.

An easy optimization is to do the DP table only for size `(k+1) * (n+1)`, as follows:

```
D(0,i) = true     i >= 0
D(x,0) = false    x != 0
D(x,i) = D((x-arr[i])%k,i-1) OR D(x,i-1)
```

The above is true because `(a-b)%k = (a%k - b%k)%k` (where %k for negative numbers is defined as the [complementary modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation).

Now, when you are done setting your table you can search if there is any `x` such that `((2x)%k - SUM%k) %k == 0`. It works because for each subset that sums to `t`:

```
(2t - SUM) % k = ((2t)%k - SUM%k) %k = (2(t%k))%k - SUM%k) % k = ((2x)%k - SUM%k) %k
```

Comment: This algorithm is exactly the same as what I came up with :D. What bothers me is that I don't know why it is equivalent to the subset sum problem, even though it feels intuitive

Comment: @PasserBy I might have misunderstood you - your question states a `O(2^n)` solution. I offered a `O(SUM*n)` solution, which is improvement to the suggestion.

Comment: @PasserBy Also note that by setting `k>SUM`, this decays into partition problem, you might be optimize it though for small values of `k` - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: oops my mistake I misunderstood something

Comment: @PasserBy Added optimization that shows it can be optimized to `O(n*k)`. Still pseudo polynomial, but in `k`, which can be huge difference for `k<<SUM`.